# How to show Spinner With Label (Static Text)?

Tags: android, spinner

I want to show spinner with static small label above it how it can be possible 
seen one of the popular app want to show same like it.

Here is my image, red marked one is the spinner with gray colored text above it which does not changes

**I don't want to show `android:prompt` which shows default text inside spinner
want to show exact above the spinner in same control**

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

for this you will have to create custom spinner:

layout of spinner according to your need name it as `custom_spinner`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tVStaticSmallLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="static text"
        android:textColor="#777777"
        android:textSize="22px" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tVMainText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tVStaticSmallLabel"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:text="your changing text" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

in activity give this layout to the spinner:

```
Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.yourSpinner);
        mySpinner.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this, R.layout.custom_spinner,
                spinnerValues));
```

Comment: You should use `sp` instead of pixels for `textSize`.

Comment: You talk about creating a custom spinner named `custom_spinner` but the layout provided doesn't even contain a spinner named `custom_spinner` that example is not helping.

Comment: you are taking it wrong, custom_spinner is the new layout that you will inflate to your adapter it's not the spinner that you have added in your layout file. adapter inflate the layout to your spinner according to your given designed layout. @ChristianBeer

Answer (score 1):

That title is nothing but a [TextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html).

Comment: how can be that bcz when i click spinner both textView and spinner get clicked

Comment: @AditiK have you mentioned this in question?

Answer (score 0):

I believe, it is a VerticalLayout with 2 items inside: one TextView and the other Spinner